# How to generate a self-signed certificate for use with Network.TLS

Tags: haskell, ssl

I am writing a program to run on a single server that I control, that accepts connections from clients.  The data needs to be encrypted, and server authentication is a nice touch.  I'm planning to use the [tls package from Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tls), as it provides both client and server encryption functionality.

I'm trying to generate a key and convert it to the [`X509`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/certificate/latest/doc/html/Data-Certificate-X509.html#t%3aX509) type, needed for the [`pCertificates`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tls/latest/doc/html/Network-TLS.html#v%3apCertificates) parameter to Network.TLS.  I generated the key using [GnuTLS's certtool](http://www.gnu.org/s/gnutls/manual/html_node/Invoking-certtool.html), following the directions under "Self-signed certificate generation":

```
certtool --generate-privkey --outfile ca-key.pem
certtool --generate-self-signed --load-privkey ca-key.pem --outfile ca-cert.pem
```

Here is the program I'm using to try to decode the X509 file:

```
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.Certificate.PEM
import Data.Certificate.X509

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

decode :: ByteString -> Either String X509
decode pem =
    case parsePEMCert pem of
        Nothing       -> Left "certificate not in PEM format"
        Just certdata -> decodeCertificate $ L.fromChunks [certdata]

main :: IO ()
main = print . decode =<< B.readFile "ca-cert.pem"
```

It parses the PEM wrapper successfully, but does not recognize the data within:

```
$ ./decode
Left "certificate error: \"subject public key bad format : [OID [1,2,840,113549,1,1,1]]\""
```

Is this a bug in the tls package?  Or am I not generating the right type of file by using the `certtool` commands above?

Comment: I have tried running your program with a variety of certool outputs and they all work.  Are you sure you're using the latest `certificate` package?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Yes, it still happens with `certificate-0.9.5`.  However, I am using GnuTLS version 2.8.5.  I'll try version 3.0.5 and see what happens.

Comment: Just FYI, this works for me using ghc 7.2.1, certificate-0.9.5, and certtool 2.10.5 (gnutls 2.8.6). EDIT: Also tested/working with GHC 7.0.1 and certificate-0.9.4.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, 64-bit.  I wonder if that influences anything.  Still waiting for gnutls to compile.

Comment: @Thomas M. Dubuisson: It worked when I used GnuTLS 3.0.4 instead.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello @JoeyAdams . I am having the same problem, with a locally root-signed certificate. All clients can connect, but my haskell program keeps refusing the TLS handshake, with the exact same error message as you. Could you give feedback on how you solved that ? Did you just switch to gnutls 3 ? This is hardly an option on my environment. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulR: Yes, I just used certtool in GnuTLS 3.0.4.

Comment: @JoeyAdams : thank you very much. I could build locally a newer version of gnutls, and the new certificate managed to get through this step. Unfortunatly, it still does not work due to this error : Error_Protocol ("certificate rejected: chain doesn't match each other",True,CertificateUnknown)

Comment: For future references, we worked around the issue by generating the certificate with OpenSSL toolchain, which seems to be better supported by the tls package.

Comment: @PaulR: since your comment provides a solution to this issue, you should submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Community-wiki answer with two solutions from the comments.

1) It worked when I used GnuTLS 3.0.4 instead.

2) For future references, we worked around the issue by generating the certificate with OpenSSL toolchain, which seems to be better supported by the tls package.